# AWS CDK EcsDeployAction update existing Fargate Service

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-fargate

I'm deployng Fargate services through AWS CDK with ease.

Now I need to update a service, for instance a task image.
I 'm trying to accomplish this by using @aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline and the action EcsDeployAction

I'm trying to import and update an existing (previously deployed) fargate service, like this:

```
const pipeline = new codepipeline.Pipeline(this, 'MyPipeline')

// import an existing fargate service
const fargateService = ecs.FargateService.fromFargateServiceArn(
  this,
  "FargateService",
  "MyFargateServiceARN"
);

// Deploy a new version according to what 
const sourceStage = this.pipeline.addStage({
  stageName: 'Deploy',
  actions: [
    new codepipeline_actions.EcsDeployAction({
      actionName: "ECS-Service",
      service: fargateService,       <--- here the typescript error
      input: ...
    })
  ]
})
```

But it does not seem correct because I get a typescript error:

```
Property 'cluster' is missing in type 'IFargateService' but required in type 'IBaseService'
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a type mismatch.  `EcsDeployActionProps` [expects the service prop](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/2dea31a581e7e066195eee30aa93616b123c2ee4/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline-actions/lib/ecs/deploy-action.ts#L15) to be of the type `IBaseService`.  But it's getting an incompatible `IFargateService` type from `fromFargateServiceArn`.

Luckily, the related [static fromFargateServiceAttributes(scope, id, attrs)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ecs.FargateService.html#static-fromwbrfargatewbrservicewbrattributesscope-id-attrs) returns the compatible type `IBaseService` you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this approach, for sure it will work.